# Configurar Github no Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, github

Alguém poderia me ajudar na configuração para integrar a IDE Eclipse com o Github, para então permitir eu subir os meus projetos em desenvolvimento, e quando necessário realizar o import?

Eu tentei, mas sem sucesso, se alguém tiver conhecimento e puder me auxiliar eu agradeço!

Eu tentei seguir os passos que você me passou, mas me surgiu uma dúvida, por exemplo eu tenho um diretório de trabalho C:\Users\Diego\workspace, e quero subir o projeto no Github **HelloWorld** eu preciso clonar meu repositório em qual pasta? Preciso criar uma nova pasta e salvar um novo projeto nesta? Não estou conseguindo entender muito bem, eu nunca configurei o Git com o Github, por favor, me ajude.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A configuração e utilização de git junto com github e independente de eclipse. Para descarregar o cliente git pode acessar a:
    https://git-scm.com/download/win
Se você querê descarregar um projeto de um repositório de github dentro de um pasta executar

```
git init 
git remote add origin https://github.com/repositorio/projeto.git
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

Depois só precisa importar o projeto em eclipse e trabalhar normalmente.Apos realizar alguma mudança para subir essa mudança no repositório executar:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "descrição do das mudanças do commit"
git push origin master
```

Comment: Olá Marcos. Vou executar conforme os passos que você descreveu, qualquer dúvida escrevo novamente.

Comment: Olá Marcos. Na instalação do Git preciso selecionar qual opção [ ] Use Git from Gir Bash Only, [ ] Use Git from the Window Command Prompt, [ ] Use Git and optional Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Use Git from the Window Command Prompt. Deixo um video de exemplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0elqVtkicJE

Comment: Olá Marcos. Vou verificar, muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá Marcos. Eu não consegui entender como é a funcionalidade do Git, visualizei o Vídeo, mas no entanto não consegui compreender, preciso entender a estrutura.

Comment: Sege esse tutoria  lhttp://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

Comment: Olá Marcos. Vou verificar! Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Olá Marcos. Eu complementei a minha pergunta.